# socket.io-client - connection problem (reactjs)

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I see that the client is receiving messages from the server (see screenshot).
[browser network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6lBx.png)

But the client doesn't respond to these messages.

```
const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false,
})
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('oper', data => {
      console.log('oper 111111111111111111')
    })
}, []);
```

This is what I see when I write console.log(socket).

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyKOk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cause
On the server socket.io version 2, on the client - 3. I downgraded the version and it all worked.